# Tikz image between lines

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to place a tikz image between text, but it seems that I can't.

This is the code I'm using

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcommand*{\lb}{\llbracket}
\newcommand*{\rb}{\rrbracket}
\newcommand*{\mean}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{m}}}
\newcommand*{\sust}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{s}}}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.75em}
\begin{document}

Something 1

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,auto,node distance=2.25cm,
thin,main node/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.4cm}]

\node[main node] (0) {$S_1$};
\node[main node] (1) [right of=0] {$S_2$};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(0) edge [bend left] node [above] {$\lb\mathbb{O}\rb^m$} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Something 2

\end{document}
```

And I want the text to appear between something 1 and something 2.

Comment: if you don't want it to float about, don't put it in a floating environment like `figure`.  Just try it without the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` tags.

Comment: @Thruston Then where do I put the centering tag?

Comment: Remove `\centering` and use `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` instead of `\begin{figure} .. \end{figure}`